# Need help databinding an ArrayList of ListItems

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, .net-1.1

I am databinding a dropdown list with the following array list:

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
al.Add(new ListItem("Service Types", 1));
al.Add(new ListItem("Expense Types", 2));
al.Add(new ListItem("Payment Terms", 3));
al.Add(new ListItem("Classes", 4));
al.Add(new ListItem("Project", 5));
al.Add(new ListItem("Employees", 6));
al.Add(new ListItem("Payroll Codes", 7));

ddlType.DataSource = al;
ddlType.DataBind();
```

This results in  the following HTML:

```
<select name="ddlType">
    <option value="Service Types">Service Types</option>
    <option value="Expense Types">Expense Types</option>
    <option value="Payment Terms">Payment Terms</option>
    <option value="Classes">Classes</option>
    <option value="Project">Project</option>
    <option value="Employees">Employees</option>
    <option value="Payroll Codes">Payroll Codes</option>
</select>
```

How can I set the DataTextField and DataValueField properties on my dropdown so that the values of the list items are the values in the dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

Why bother with databinding at all. You can populate the items collection directly:

```
ddlType.Items.Add(new ListItem("Service Types", 1));
...
ddlType.Items.Add(new ListItem("Payroll Codes", 7));
```

and it will even make your code 3 lines shorter ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an Instead of an `ArrayList` containg `ListItems` why don't you create a `Hashtable`?

```
Hashtable hash = new Hashtable();
hash.Add("one", "1")
hash.Add("two", "2")

dd.DataSource = ht
dd.DataTextField = "value"
dd.DataValueField = "key"
dd.DataBind()
```

Comment: It doesn't work in .NET 1.1 - a HashTable is the best solution for .NET 1.1

Comment: Are you seeing an error or does it still bind to the first element each time?

Comment: Binds to the first element each time.

Comment: Fixed the typo -- the collection is Hashtable

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a ListItemCollection and binding to that?

Answer (score -1):

```
ddlType.DataTextField = "Text";
ddlType.DataValueField = "Value";
```

Comment: -1 this does not work in .NET 1.1 - databiding is much more sophisticated in later versions of the framework.